# Subtraction is not working on a variable

Tags: javascript

I can not figure out why the subtraction from a number variable is not working. My code is below.

```
function Check() {
var Viewer = document.getElementById("Viewer");
var TrysLeft = 3;
    if (Viewer.value == Num) {
    alert("Correct");
    } else {
    TrysLeft - 1;
    alert("Sorry you got the combo wrong! You have " + TrysLeft + " Trys left before the combo is reset");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `var TrysLeft = 3;` as a local variable.  It's re-initializing it to 3 each time you call the function.

You also didn't assign TrysLeft to anything after you subtracted it. 
You can either do `TrysLeft--;` or `TrysLeft = TrysLeft  -1;`

Comment: @Kevin Good eye there!

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
TrysLeft = TrysLeft - 1;
```

Or

```
TrysLeft -= 1;
```

Comment: That's the same as `TrysLeft--;`, which is less code.

Comment: I agree with you @PHPglue. I was about to change it but you have it also as your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following code:

```
TrysLeft--;
```

or

```
--TrysLeft;
```

Also, I recomend keeping variables lowercase, that aren't functions or Objects.

Answer (score 1):

First, correct the line with:

`TrysLeft = -1;`

by:

`TrysLeft -= 1;`

**Next:**

You can use a closure to keep the current value of the variable each time the function is called:

```
var TrysLeft = 3;

function Check() {
var Viewer = document.getElementById("Viewer");
    if (Viewer.value == Num) {
    alert("Correct");
    } else {
    `TrysLeft -= 1;`
    alert("Sorry you got the combo wrong! You have " + TrysLeft + " Trys left before the combo is reset");
    }
}
```

Comment: That just changed the variable to - 1

Comment: Remove the space in the answer so that it's `TrysLeft -= 1`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try

```
TrysLeft=TrysLeft-1;
```